# How to add "Find" function to IList

Tags: c#, list, find, ilist

I am returning IList from Business layer. But in viewmodel I have to use Find function.
One method is to convert IList to List.

But is there anyway to add "Find" method to IList

Comment: Just create your own IFindableList : IList implementation that includes the Find functionality. Since you control your own BL code you can return this FindableList

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there are the Linq extension methods `.Where` (to fecth all that match) and `.FirstOrDefault` (to fetch the first match) or you can write your own extension method against IList like:

```
public static class IListExtensions
{
    public static T FindFirst<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        foreach(T item in source)
            if(condition(item))
                return item;
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add this file to my .cs project, Can I access IListVar.FindFirst() ?

Comment: Yes, as long as IListExtensions is in scope you will be able to call a FindFirst method against any IList<T>.

Comment: What is ToList() method in Linq ?..Can I use this

Comment: ToList will turn an IEnumerable<T> into a List<T>.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the IndexOf method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w0148af.aspx

Comment: If you're using .net 3.5 or 5 you can use the .Select and get all elements in the IList that satisfy a condition  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx

Comment: Is there anyway to Add these functions to IList

Comment: I think that because an IList is IEnumerable that it already has these extension methods, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx .

Comment: Although, this is an IList<T>, you might have to cast to your specific type.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Where method

```
list.Where(predicate).First()
```

Comment: list.First(predicate) will perform better than list.Where(predicate).First() as the second will enumerate all the list looking for more than one occurrence

Comment: First() will raise an exception if item is not found, you want FirstOrDefault() to be the same behaviour as Find()

Answer (score 0):

very simple, `just you need`

> casting step

```
var myModelasList= IListReturnedViewModel as List<ViewModelObject>;
//now you can use list feaures like Find Func.
myModelasList.Find((t => t.SomeFiald== currentState && t.IsSomting == somesymbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension method to do the casting for me.

```
public static T Find<T>(this IList<T> ilist, Predicate<T> match)
{
  if (ilist is List<T> list)
  {
    return list.Find(match);
  }
  else if (ilist is T[] array)
  {
    return Array.Find(array, match);
  }
  else
  {
    return ilist.FirstOrDefault(i => match(i));
  }
}
```